# Why isn't the compiler able to deduct Compare for this templated function with a default parameter?

Tags: c++

I can't understand why my compiler can't infer the type of `Compare` in this code.
I've tried with GGC and Clang.

```
template <typename T, typename Compare>
void sort(std::vector<T>& v, Compare comp = std::less<T>())
{
    sort(v.begin(), v.end(), comp);
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v;
    sort(v/*, std::less<int>()*/);
}
```

Try the code: https://ideone.com/uCrHm6

Comment: With regards to your ideone code--adding `using namespace std;` while also making functions with the same names as std functions is probably not a good idea... (I don't think that's your problem here, but it could definitely cause issues down the line)

Comment: Regarding the dupe, you can also get a bit of sugar by changing the defaulted parameter to `Compare comp = {}` after defaulting the template parameter to avoid repeating the type. As hinted by the comments in one answer, you can also use `std::less<>` instead of `std::less<T>` if using C++14 or later.

Comment: Thanks chris. That's a very cool trick